selenium proxy credentials seems to not being detected with python
Hello i try to use selenium for making a botnet for my cybersecurity work for my school but it show this error i use gecko ( Firefox ) driver
i got this error : Error with proxy 217****:50100:steixv:T*fZwpn3: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# List of proxies with credentials in the format IP:Port:Username:Password
proxy_list = [
    "ip:port:username:password",
    # Add more proxies as needed
]

# Function to set proxy and initialize WebDriver
def set_proxy(proxy):
    ip_port_user_pass = proxy.split(':')
    ip = ip_port_user_pass[0]
    port = ip_port_user_pass[1]
    username = ip_port_user_pass[2]
    password = ip_port_user_pass[3]
    
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    
    # Configure proxy settings
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://{}:{}'.format(ip, port))
    
    # Set proxy authentication credentials
    options.add_argument('--proxy-auth={}:{}'.format(username, password))

    # Set Firefox to use the options
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    
    return driver

# Function to fill out and submit the form
def fill_form(driver):
    driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')  # Replace with your actual form URL
    
    # Locate form elements and fill them out
    name_field = driver.find_element_by_name('name')
    name_field.send_keys('John Doe')
    
    email_field = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    email_field.send_keys('john.doe@example.com')
    
    # Submit the form
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
    submit_button.click()

    # Wait to see the result
    time.sleep(2)

# Loop through proxies and submit the form
for proxy in proxy_list:
    try:
        driver = set_proxy(proxy)
        fill_form(driver)
        driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error with proxy {proxy}: {e}')

print('Form submission completed.')


i try to use chatgpt but even him cant solve my problem
